# Container View with UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uicontainerview

I have created a `UIViewController` that contains a single `UIStackView`.  I then dragged 2 separate "container view" objects from the Interface Builder and placed them within the `UIStackView`.  I set everything to display them equal size, and everything looks fine as shown below.

[image]

I then tried to embed the left `UIViewController` inside a `UITabBarController`, and the right UIViewController within a `UINavigationController`.  When I do this, the `UITabBarController` itself renders properly, but *nothing else* does.  The "Right Child VC"/"Left Child VC" `UILabel`s you see in the first image do not appear.  Also, the `UINavigationBar` I would expect to see in the right-hand `UINavigationController`/`UIViewController` is not rendered at all.  (See below)

[image]

Is this not a supported view hierarchy?  Or is there something I'm missing when sketching out my UI?  It's a pretty simple setup, so I'm sure I must be doing something wrong here.  I just can't figure out what.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problems with your layout. I'd suggest either starting again from scratch, or just looking closely at what you have to try and find the issue.

Here's an example I just did:

[image]

Here's the source for the Storyboard (not using any code at all). Maybe it will help you find your issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="a3E-zy-HPT">
    <device id="ipad9_7" orientation="landscape">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="b2n-7J-CgC">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="a3E-zy-HPT" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="KZ3-dF-um0">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="1024" height="768"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="20" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="isF-Am-gyT">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="40" width="984" height="708"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <containerView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tSf-1c-DXK">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="482" height="708"/>
                                        <connections>
                                            <segue destination="a6c-TQ-han" kind="embed" id="wJI-Oa-9d8"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </containerView>
                                    <containerView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Cbg-8F-i9g">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="502" y="0.0" width="482" height="708"/>
                                        <connections>
                                            <segue destination="j5j-RN-MXn" kind="embed" id="xcH-30-iu7"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </containerView>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="isF-Am-gyT" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6ov-Cy-Ir7" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="USK-a7-tSI"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6ov-Cy-Ir7" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="isF-Am-gyT" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="VsI-nn-Lkr"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6ov-Cy-Ir7" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="isF-Am-gyT" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="XCt-l8-Yb9"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="isF-Am-gyT" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6ov-Cy-Ir7" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="oyc-rl-VH4"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6ov-Cy-Ir7"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="E22-5h-DVF" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="122" y="107"/>
        </scene>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="0NG-jb-kKA">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="aUN-mz-OsG" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="TYT-qP-0f7">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="482" height="708"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Nav Root VC" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="jot-50-nWz">
                                <rect key="frame" x="153" y="334.5" width="176" height="39"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="32"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.83234566450000003" blue="0.47320586440000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="jot-50-nWz" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="TYT-qP-0f7" secondAttribute="centerY" id="28z-MT-YCI"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="jot-50-nWz" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="TYT-qP-0f7" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Gi7-4Y-AjH"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="RRI-ma-q1W"/>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="hOU-IQ-1El"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="SbD-h6-Vqx" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="754" y="798"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Item 2-->
        <scene sceneID="2wS-Zh-sav">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="Eti-JO-pq9" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="HfC-oh-jte">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="482" height="708"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Second Tab" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="acL-vG-z3l">
                                <rect key="frame" x="160.5" y="335" width="161.5" height="38.5"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="32"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.46202266219999999" green="0.83828371759999998" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="acL-vG-z3l" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="HfC-oh-jte" secondAttribute="centerX" id="2Oh-Nh-GJB"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="acL-vG-z3l" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="HfC-oh-jte" secondAttribute="centerY" id="q1E-kw-utV"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="Biq-1g-K08"/>
                    </view>
                    <tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="Item 2" id="RQo-7T-lpL"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="uxd-vy-6z6" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="122" y="1485"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Item 1-->
        <scene sceneID="lGr-eZ-se1">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="PIq-bk-5i9" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="5EA-RT-arW">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="482" height="708"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="First Tab" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="MqF-oN-08O">
                                <rect key="frame" x="183" y="335" width="116" height="38.5"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="32"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.83216959239999999" green="0.98548370600000001" blue="0.47333085539999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="MqF-oN-08O" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="5EA-RT-arW" secondAttribute="centerY" id="adF-hp-Zru"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="MqF-oN-08O" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="5EA-RT-arW" secondAttribute="centerX" id="kBQ-9K-Y1g"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="48X-sh-gIQ"/>
                    </view>
                    <tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="Item 1" id="tNF-6e-qoJ"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="uHV-RY-oqY" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-372" y="1473"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Tab Bar Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="C5L-yQ-vn8">
            <objects>
                <tabBarController id="a6c-TQ-han" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tabBar key="tabBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="pkv-HU-5fb">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="49"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                    </tabBar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="PIq-bk-5i9" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="3EH-dA-L0h"/>
                        <segue destination="Eti-JO-pq9" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="tvF-0L-zgq"/>
                    </connections>
                </tabBarController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="2cT-d5-vXz" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-132" y="798"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="O3Z-Ku-kaQ">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="j5j-RN-MXn" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="EXg-9E-uJx">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="482" height="50"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="aUN-mz-OsG" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="Bp8-wj-NyV"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="TH6-8z-qVz" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="411" y="798"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```